# Paramiko: read from standard output of remotely executed command

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

so I was working with paramiko for some basic SSH testing and I'm not getting any output into stdout. Heres my code.

```
import paramiko
client=paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
com="ls ~/desktop"
client.connect('MyIPAddress',MyPortNumber, username='username', password='password')
output=""
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(com)

print "ssh succuessful. Closing connection"
client.close()
print "Connection closed"
stdout=stdout.readlines()
print stdout
print com
for line in stdout:
    output=output+line
if output!="":
    print output
else:
    print "There was no output for this command"
```

So whenever I run this, the command is executed (as seen by if I do something like a cp, the file is copied), but I always get "There was no output for this command". When stdout=stdout.readlines() is printed, [] is the output. In addition, if I add a print statement into the for loop, it never gets run. Could someone help me out here? Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have closed the connection before reading lines:

```
import paramiko
client=paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
com="ls ~/desktop"
client.connect('MyIPAddress',MyPortNumber, username='username', password='password')
output=""
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(com)

print "ssh succuessful. Closing connection"
stdout=stdout.readlines()
client.close()
print "Connection closed"

print stdout
print com
for line in stdout:
    output=output+line
if output!="":
    print output
else:
    print "There was no output for this command"
```

Comment: @jabaldonedo I have tried this code with my project, what I am having an issue with is that I SSH in and when it gets to any stdout.read() line it hangs. Like using the above code it gets to `print "ssh successful. Closing connection"` and stops. I can't even CTRL+C to get out. Can't seem to find a fix for this.

Comment: Indeed, this code may hang, if the command produces also error output, see [Paramiko ssh die/hang with big output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625788/850848).

Answer (score 5):

The code in the accepted answer may hang, if the command produces also an error output. See [Paramiko ssh die/hang with big output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625788/850848).

An easy solution, if you do not mind merging `stdout` and `stderr`, is to combine them into one stream using [`Channel.set_combine_stderr`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.set_combine_stderr):

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
stdout.channel.set_combine_stderr(True)
output = stdout.readlines()
```

---

If you need to read the outputs separately, see [Run multiple commands in different SSH servers in parallel using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66191219/850848).

Answer (score 2):

***Interactive example ：
====Part 1， this show the sh output in server ，at the end of is ">"
 need some input to continual or exit ======**

selilsosx045:uecontrol-CXC_173_6456-R32A01 lteue$     ./uecontrol.sh -host localhost
UE Control:Start UE control using:
UE Control:java -Dlogdir= -Duecontrol.configdir=./etc -jar ./server/server-R32A01.jar -host localhost
Loading properties from file /Users/lteue/Downloads/uecontrol-CXC_173_6456-R32A01/etc/uecontrol.properties
Starting remote CLI towards host localhost
Enter the command Q to exit the CLI, or the command HELP
to get information on available commands.
The CLI is ready for input.
**uec>**

**===========Pyhton code with peramiko ============***

Try below method ： while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():

```
def shCommand(server_list):
server_IP = server_list[0]
username  = server_list[1]
password  = server_list[2]

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(server_IP,22,username, password)strong text

commandList = ['list \n']
alldata = getUeInfo(ssh,commandList)
ssh.close()

def getUeInfo(ssh,commandList):
data_buffer = ""
num_of_input = 0
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cmd')
while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
   solo_line = ""        

   if stdout.channel.recv_ready():

      solo_line = stdout.channel.recv(1024)  # Retrieve the first 1024 bytes
      data_buffer += solo_line               


   if(cmp(solo_line,'uec> ') ==0 ):    #len of solo should be 5 ,
     if num_of_input == 0 :
      data_buffer = ""    
      for cmd in commandList :
       #print cmd
       stdin.channel.send(cmd)
      num_of_input += 1
     if num_of_input == 1 :
      stdin.channel.send('q \n') 
      num_of_input += 1

return data_buffer
```

Answer (score 1):

As @jabaldonedo said you closed your SSHClient connection before reading the `stdout`.  SSHClient can be used as a context manager.  Using the SSHClient as a context manager helps prevent you from trying to access `stdout` and `stderr` after the ssh connection is closed.  The resulting code in Python3 syntax looks like:

```
from paramiko import AutoAddPolicy, SSHClient

with SSHClient() as client:
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy)
    client.connect(
        'MyIPAddress',
        MyPortNumber, 
        username='username', 
        password='password'
    )

    com = "ls ~/desktop"
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(com)

    output = ''
    for line in stdout.readlines()
        output += line

if output:
    print(output)
else:
    print("There was no output for this command")
```

Comment: OK, but your code still suffers the same deadlock problem as the code by @jabaldonedo.

Comment: What deadlock problem is that?  The connection is still open when stdout is read and SSHClient.__exit__ will take care of closing the connection at the end of the with block.

Comment: I've linked the problem in my comment to the @jabaldonedo's answer already. If you need it repeated, here it is: [Paramiko ssh die/hang with big output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625788/850848).

Answer (score -1):

```py
# Program to print the output in console/interpreter/shell in runtime without using stdout.

 import paramiko
 import xlrd
 import time

 ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
 ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

 loc = ('/Users/harshgow/Documents/PYTHON_WORK/labcred.xlsx')
 wo = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
 sheet = wo.sheet_by_index(0)
 Host = sheet.cell_value(0, 1)
 Port = int(sheet.cell_value(3, 1))
 User = sheet.cell_value(1, 1)
 Pass = sheet.cell_value(2, 1)

 def details(Host, Port, User, Pass):
       time.sleep(2)

       ssh.connect(Host, Port, User, Pass)
       print('connected to ip ', Host)

       stdin = ssh.exec_command("")
       remote_conn = ssh.invoke_shell()
       print("Interactive SSH session established")

       output = remote_conn.recv(1000)
       remote_conn.send("\n")
       remote_conn.send("xstatus Cameras\n")

       time.sleep(5)
       output = remote_conn.recv(10000)
       print(output)

 details(Host, Port, User, Pass)
```

Comment: I used your method to get to an interactive menu. I want to type "R" and press Enter, but the remote_conn.send("R\n") doesn't do anything. The shell is not taking the "R". What can I do here? Doing stdin.write("R") returns 'tuple does not have method write'