# Comparing MD5 of downloaded files against files on an SFTP server in Python

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, md5, paramiko

Here I am trying to list all the MD5's of the files I downloaded and compare them to the original to see if they are the same Files.
I can't access a server to test this code right now but I was really curious if it would work...
Does someone have a better solution or something they would change?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import paramiko
import pysftp
import os
import sys

print("Localpath eingeben: ")
localpath = input()
print("Remothpath eingeben: ")
remotepath = input()
k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("/home/abdulkarim/.ssh/id_rsa")
c = paramiko.SSHClient()
c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print("connecting")
c.connect(hostname = "do-test", username = "abdulkarim", pkey = k)
print("connected")
sftp = c.open_sftp()
sftp.Connection.get_d(localpath, remotepath)
#sftp.get_d(localpath, remotepath)

def hashCheckDir(f,r):
    files = []
    # r=root, d=directories, f=files
    for r, d, f in os.walk(localpath):
        for file in f:
            if '.txt' in file:
                files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
    files1 = []
    # r=root, d=directories, f=files
    for r, d, f in os.walk(remotepath):
        for file in f:
            if '.txt' in file:
                files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

    for i in range(2):
        for x in files:
            localsum = os.system('md5sum ' + files)
            remotesum = os.system('ssh do-test md5sum ' + files1)
            if localsum == remotesum:
                print ("The lists are identical")
            else :
                print ("The lists are not identical")

hashCheckDir(localpath,remotepath)
c.close()
```

I am pretty new to Python so.. Bear with me if I did some stupid mistake.
Maybe I have to sort them first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an overkill to launch an external console application (`ssh`) to execute `md5sum` on the server (and open a new connection for each and every file on top of that), if you already have a native Python SSH connection to the same server.

Instead [use `SSHClient.exec_command`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17137859/850848):

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = c.exec_command('md5sum '+ files1)
checksum = stdout.read()
```

*Note that MD5 is obsolete, use SHA-256 (`sha256sum`).*

---

Though question is whether the whole checksum check isn't an overkill, see:
[How to perform checksums during a SFTP file transfer for data integrity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30056566/850848)

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848)*.