# How do i use subprocess Popen module to initiate ping to multiple IPs simultaneously from a different host

Tags: python, subprocess

Im a new bie to python programming and writing a script to login to a linux machine (from a server) and check for connectivity to multiple IPs in a quick manner.  i came across this thread  [Multiple ping script in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101239/multiple-ping-script-in-python/12102040#12102040)  which uses subprocess.Popen and does it fast but it does check for ping from the server where the script is run rather than the linux machine

I have the code to ssh to the linux machine and get its handle. snippet below
is there a way to pass on this handle to the subprocess.Popen so that the ping can be checked from the linux machine instead of the server.

I tried to read the documentation of subprocess.Popen but could not get a clarity.

kindly help.

```
    ssh = SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.load_system_host_keys()
    for x in range(retries):
        try:
            ssh.connect(ip, username = username , password = password)
            log.info('Connected to the machine {0} successfully..'.format(ip))
            return ssh
        except (paramiko.BadHostKeyException, paramiko.AuthenticationException, paramiko.SSHException, socket.error) as e:
            log.info('Exception : {0}'.format(e))
            return False
```

I used the code  using subprocess.call() from the same link pasted above but that is not quick enough..

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to use `ssh` instead of `subprocess` to run a command on the remote host. The interface is slightly different but it's not hard to adapt your code once you understand what's wrong. `subprocess` still runs on your local computer, as you note

Comment: I;m able to achieve that by using exec_command(<ping ip>) but that is pretty slow as i see . so was wondering if there is a better way to do it

Comment: The `Popen` solution you looked at created many `ping` processes running in parallel. I believe you can do that with Paramiko too but I'm not particularly familiar with the library so I leave it to somebody else to straighten you out on how exactly to do that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66191219/run-multiple-commands-in-different-ssh-servers-in-parallel-using-python-paramiko has a recipe for running on multiple servers in parallel but perhaps it could be simplified to run on just one host.