# Read command output in Paramiko without prompts and other shell output

Tags: python, shell, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to send an output of a specific command to a txt file,

```
file = 'output_from_the_server.txt'

def connect(host):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(hostname=host, port=port, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
    ssh = client.invoke_shell()
    return ssh

def test(server_host):
    print(server_host)
    IP = server_view(server_host)
    print(IP)
    ssh = connect(IP)
    time.sleep(2)
    ssh.send('clear -x && [command]\n')
    time.sleep(3)
    resp = ssh.recv(655353)
    output = resp.decode('ascii').split(',')
    output = ''.join(output)
    ssh.close()

    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        for i in output:
            f.write(i)
    f.close()
```

The file include all of the outputs before the command, even i tried to use clear screen.

Answer (score 1):

You are starting a shell, so naturally you get all the output you would get in the shell, including all prompts and banners.

Do not use shell to automate command execution, use the "exec" SSH channel.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
stdout.channel.set_combine_stderr(True)
output = stdout.readlines()
```

See [Paramiko: read from standard output of remotely executed command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17137859/850848#70863884).

---

Related question:
[Is there a simple way to get rid of junk values that come when you SSH using Python's Paramiko library and fetch output from CLI of a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33291631/850848)

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` on its own – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of executing a command through a paramiko.

Sending the output to a file should then be easy.

```
def ssh_command(ip, user, command):
    key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(os.getenv('HOME') + '/.ssh/paramiko')
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(ip, username=user, pkey=key)
    ssh_session = client.get_transport().open_session()
    if ssh_session.active:
        ssh_session.exec_command(command)
        out = []
        r = ssh_session.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        while r:
            out.append(r)
            r = ssh_session.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')

        return ''.join(out)
    return ''

res = ssh_command('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'cd / ; ls */ | xargs ls')
for outputin str(res).split('\\n'):
    print(output)
```

Don't forget to generate a key with ssh-keygen.

Comment: You can achieve the same and more reliably with much less code. See my answer.

Comment: ah yes didn't know about that. thanks!