# Get available disk space from SFTP Server

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I’m trying to retrieve the free available disk space I have on my SFTP server. The SFTP server runs on Windows platform and my SFTP client is running on a Linux Docker container. I am using SFTP Paramiko API. I do not have ssh installed on my docker container. Anyone got any idea?

I’m trying to get the free space of drive `C` of my SFTP server running on Windows.

This piece of code below runs in my Docker container.

```
def get_free_space(host, port, user, pwd):
    client = paramiko.client.sshclient()
    client.connect(host, user, pwd)
    stdin, stdout, stderr =    client.exec_command(“df -h” + “C:/“) 
    print(stdout.readlines())
    print(stderr.readlines())
```

However, there is this error stating

> 'df' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Core SFTP protocol does not have API to obtain free disk space.

There are two SFTP extensions that can do that though.

The standard extension is `space-available`, but that's not supported by the most widespread SFTP server, the OpenSSH.

On the other hand OpenSSH support its own proprietary extension `statvfs@openssh.com`.

Paramiko supports neither. But it's not difficult to implement them.

For instance for `statvfs@openssh.com`:

```
sftp = client.open_sftp()

path = "/remote/path"

path = sftp._adjust_cwd(path)
t, msg = sftp._request(
    CMD_EXTENDED, "statvfs@openssh.com", path
)

if t != CMD_EXTENDED_REPLY:
    raise SFTPError("Expected extended reply response")

block_size = msg.get_int64()
fundamental_block_size = msg.get_int64()
blocks = msg.get_int64()
free_blocks = msg.get_int64()
available_blocks = msg.get_int64()
file_inodes = msg.get_int64()
free_file_inodes = msg.get_int64()
available_file_inodes = msg.get_int64()
sid = msg.get_int64()
flags = msg.get_int64()
name_max = msg.get_int64()

free_bytes = block_size * free_blocks
print(free_bytes)
```

---

Or if you have a shell access to the server, execute respective shell command to obtain the disk space.

- On Linux, use `df`.
- On Windows, see [Free space in a CMD shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/293780/850848).

See [Paramiko: read from standard output of remotely executed command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17137859/850848#70863884)

Though this is not *SFTP* anymore.